# Are meta questions on the decrease and if so, why?

Tags: discussion

Just looking at the "newest" questions list on IPS meta I am surprised to find that only 12 questions have been asked in the first 15 days of this month. I sense that is a low rate of new meta questions compared to all previous fortnights. Could that be explained by  some factor such as that (I don't know whether this is a fact, or any possible reason why) overall number of posts is typically low in January on Stack Exchange? Or,

**are IPS meta questions on the decrease and if so, why?**

Comment: That's the first January IPS experiences, so how shall we know?

Comment: For a beta site less than a year old, a bit under 1 meta question/day isn't bad. And as long as people aren't ignoring serious issues, it's not a problem.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear @Anne Daunted: is overall number of posts typically low in January on Stack Exchange? Now edited Q to clarify.

Comment: Good to know @HDE226868.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't give questions, but look at the [variability of visits on Quantcast](https://ak.quantcast.com/interpersonal.stackexchange.com?country=BD#trafficCard):

[image]

You can see we have a massive drop off in visitors over Christmas, and it takes a while to build back up. From moderating a few other sites, I would say this looks perfectly normal.

You can get Quantcast views of many Stack Exchange sites. And even if you look at Stack Overflow, you see the same pattern - it's just scaled up massively :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rory Alsop. This is the type of graphic I remember seeing in a similar context on English.SE and explains clearly that it is a typical pattern.

Comment: Mods get a bit more detail, but I tend to use Quantcast to compare across sites if I want to check seasonal variations etc.